# I have array of plain PHP object that I want to use in conjunction with Zend_Paginator and partialLoop

Tags: zend-framework, model, zend-framework-mvc, zend-paginator

I am implementing DAO pattern in my sample app and I have plain array that contains User(domain) fetched from UserMapper I want to use Zend_Paginator with array adapter, but it does not work it only works when I use Zend_DbTable adapter which I dont want to do because it defeats the purpose of DAO.

sample code below (Not Working)

```
    $userMapper = new Application_Model_UserMapper();
    $users = $userMapper->getUsers();
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($users);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(1);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

sample code below (Working)

```
    $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
    $select = $users->fetchAll();
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(1);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Comment: I don't want to be insulting, but have you var_dumped your $users to check the array your getting?

Comment: Sure enough I have checked the array structure using Zend_Debug::dump and its ok.

Comment: "Does not work" in what sense? No results at all displayed in view-script? Incorrect pagination in view script? Are you calling the pagination control in the standard way `<?= $this->pagination($this->paginationControl, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml') ?>`

Comment: @DavidWeinraub There is no data displayed, I am passing the paginator object to a partialLoop like this `$this->partialLoop('albums/partials/_user_table.phtml', $this->paginator)` it works if I change the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the factory method and it takes 3 parameters

```
public static function factory($data, $adapter = self::INTERNAL_ADAPTER,
                               array $prefixPaths = null)
```

you may want to try

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($users, 'Array');
```

at least this way if your data is somehow incorrect you should raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve my problem, in order for array containing plain PHP objects to be recognized by the partialLoop you need to implement a toArray() method in that class and return key value pair of the attributes

```
  class Application_Model_User
  {
  private $id;
  private $first_name;
  private $last_name;
  private $middle_name;

  public function toArray()
  {
   return get_object_vars($this);
  }
  }
```